# Forgottern Pattern on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-a

Does anyone know how to reset a forgotten pattern to a Samsung Galaxy Tab A. My sister has forgotten the pattern and cannot access the tablet. Can you guys help me.

Comment: Try a factory reset.  this will wipe all data stored in the tablet though.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will need to use recovery mode and will need the Google account password linked with the device.

1. Power off the device and hold Power+VolUp+Home, then wait a minute.
2. Navigate the recovery menu with VolUp to go up and VolDown to go down, and the Power button to select.
3. Select factory reset>Yes.
4. Press "reboot system now".
5. Enter the Google account password last used with the device.

Your device should now be unlocked, and you can use it again. But none of its original data will remain (except data on the SD card). If you still have issues, contact the company and tell them your issue, and what to attempted to solve it (You will not void your warranty with the steps shown above).

For more, refer to [this article](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Phones/Recovery-Mode-and-How-to-Use-It/td-p/71015) on the Samsung website.